# How to add formcontrol to a textarea in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, textarea, angular8, angular-ngmodel

I'm working on a contact form and can't get the form to submit the textarea value using ngModel. I keep getting an error from the browser that I will post down below

I've tried using reactiveforms but end up with the same problem and error as before.

// HTML

```
<form #myform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="send(myform)" autocomplete="off">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <label>What's your name?</label>
      <input ngModel name="q1" type="text" required/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>What's your email address?</label>
      <input ngModel name="q2" type="email" required/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>What's the purpose of the message?</label>
      <div>
        <span><input ngModel id="q3a" name="q3" type="radio" value="choice1" /><label for="q3a">choice 1</label></span>
        <span><input ngModel id="q3b" name="q3" type="radio" value="choice2" /><label for="q3b">choice 2</label></span>
        <span><input ngModel id="q3c" name="q3" type="radio" value="choice3" /><label for="q3c">choice 3</label></span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>This is where your message goes!</label>
      <textArea [(ngModel)]="q4" name="q4" rows="5" cols="60" required>
      </textArea>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <input type="submit"/>
  <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
</form>
```

// Typescript

```
send(form: NgForm){
  console.log(form.value);
}
```

// Console output

```
{q1: "name", q2: "email", q3: "choice1", q4: undefined}
```

// Error

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'q4'
Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'q4'
    at _throwError (forms.js:3313)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:3139)
    at forms.js:5963
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:39698)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:358)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
    at zone-evergreen.js:855
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39679)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at zone-evergreen.js:862
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39679)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)"
```

Answer (score 2):

So this code technically had 2 different issues happening to it.

The first issue was wonderfully stated by pop.

The second issue was that the textarea didn't want to play nice with the form.

To fix the second issue, ngDefaultControl had to be added to the textarea turning the resulting textarea element to look like this after both solutions were added to it.

```
    <li>
      <label>This is where your message goes!</label>
      <textArea ngModel ngDefaultControl name="q4" rows="5" cols="60" required>
      </textArea>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this notation

```
<textArea [(ngModel)]="q4" name="q4" rows="5" cols="60" required>
```

You make Angular confused. It has both, the name and ngModel which it should handle, so it throws up the hands and says "duh", I mean, "undefined". See how you did it with inputs before? Try

```
<textArea [(ngModel)]="q4" rows="5" cols="60" required>
```

or

```
<textArea ngModel name="q4" rows="5" cols="60" required>
```

Comment: I changed it to ``` ngModel name="q4" ``` which fixed the undefined problem but the browser is still giving the same error and is now returning an empty string instead of undefined.